# Getting/Setting text on qlineedit (automation/winapi)

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, winapi

I try to fill the `qlineedits` of an external application. It has `Qt5WindowIcon` class, and I was able to find that it receives messages using WinAPI, it uses `PeekMessage`, `PostMessage` and `DefWindowProc`, but the trick is that it doesn't have any child controls this can be seen in Spy++ and also I tried manually with `EnumChildWindos` and it always returns false.

Are the Qt controls somewhat different and independent from WinAPI? I heard there are so called alien widgets, are they painted manually in user mode? I also tried setting breakpoints on `GetWindowText`, `SetWindowText`, `GetDlgItemText`, `SendMessage+WM_GETTEXT` , and I never got any bp hits, seems like Qt doesn't use this API to set/get text from `QLineEdit`.

Is there any way that I can find control id? Or the only option would be code injection with `QLineEdit` methods hooking?

Comment: The rendering of widgets is done with [`QStyle`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/style-reference.html). For rendering on Windows, there are actually two plugins: "windowsvista" and "windowsxp". (I don't know in detail how they are related to each other.) However, if you want to know details you may have a look into source code on [woboq.org](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/plugins/styles/windowsvista/). There are not so many files - thus, it may be worth.

Comment: Qt uses windowless controls by default. If you want to interact with a Qt application, you need to use [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx), and pray that Qt's implementation isn't as broken as the rest of the framework.